# Repository type recomendation

Tags: open-source

I work in the IT department as help desk, and all of the software that we use to install on our end users PCs are sitting on a network share that is only accessible to the IT department. So, the problem is this has become a cluttered mess without any organization at all, and on top of that, there are two shares that reside in different states. Sometimes software will be on one share, that is not on the other, which can become a nuisance when trying to find software. So I'm looking for something that will still allow us to have this permission based access that will sync between each other and will allow better organization. I'm open to paid options, but would rather see free, not freemiums, or FOSS that requires a configuring. We use Active Directory for our authentication and permissions, so having a program that would be more compatible with Windows is desired, but I'm open to Linux ideas as well.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if it is a 100% fit, but coming to my mind: [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) would be worth a look. I'm not using it myself and don't know it by heart, hence only a pointer in a comment.

Comment: I will look into this, but I really had something different in mind. I will edit my post to be a bit more clear. Thank you though for your suggestion! I will look into this software more to see if it would be viable. However, I would still like to hear more suggestion and I may post this on server fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the two repos available from the same networks?  Why are there two?

If there is a spot that is reachable from all places that need to get to it, start a new complete repo using whatever it is you are using now and remove the other two.  Create a process to add or change software that is there, and start it as a merge of both repos.

If it is impractical to go to one repo (geographic distance and expensive connection, limited bandwidth, etc) then "the open source way" of doing it would be to have a master with the repos you actually use updating from it.  Tools to do this would be *nix based and primarily based around `rsync` with some help from the `cron` system and some shell scripting.

There are ways of using `rsync` for Windows as well - I found reference to two programs for Windows that have `rsync` integrated to them and the "sales pitch" on the site makes it sound like it would work well for you - except it references up to Windows 7... so I don't know if it is a "dead" product...

DeltaCopy and Syncrify both available at http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

Comment: So the two network shares are for the 2 helpdesk locations that exist for the people we help. One is in one state to give the helpdesk employees the fastest possible connection to the share, and the other share is in the other state for the same purpose. For example, when I'm installing software on a users computer, I will sometimes have to navigate to the share for the other state to find what I'm looking for and sometimes an updated version.

Comment: However, I think this is on track for what I'm really after. Syncrify seems to be what I'm looking for. I will mark this as answered since it is pointing me in the direction I'm looking to go.